# Laravel 6 - undefined is not a valid timestamp. It must be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating `Calendar` using `Vue`, `Vuetify` and `Laravel`. when i tried **POST Request(create new Event)**

But i got error like this `undefined is not a valid timestamp. It must be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm`

this I got from `dd($request->all())`

```
  "color" => "#1976D2"
  "event_name" => "Heng"
  "description" => "ddd"
  "from_date" => "2020-02-14"
  "to_date" => "2020-02-15"
]
```

- `CalendarController`

```
$data  = $request->validate([
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'from_date' => 'required|date',
            'to_date' => 'required|date',
            'color' => 'required',
        ]);


        $calendar = new Calendar();
        $calendar->event_name = $request->event_name;
        $calendar->description = $request->description;
        $calendar->from_date = Carbon::parse($request->from_date)->format('Y-m-d');

        $calendar->to_date = Carbon::parse($request->to_date)->format('Y-m-d');

        $calendar->color = $request->color;
        $calendar->save();

        return response()->json(['created' => true]);
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: What do you get if you `dd($calendar)` before the save. Also are you using date casts on the `Calendar` model?

Comment: #attributes: array:5 [
    "event_name" => "Heng"
    "description" => "ddd"
    "from_date" => "2020-02-14"
    "to_date" => "2020-02-15"
    "color" => "#1976D2"
  ]

@apokryfos